# How to use regular expressions to extract information from mailto links

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a regex for the following:

> **Pattern1:**
>
> mailto:abc@gmail.com

The `regex1` should match all the strings that start with `mailto:`

> **Pattern2:**
>
> mailto:abc@gmail.com?subject=Indian&body=hello

The `regex2` should extract the query string (string after ?)

Comment: For Q2, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667278/parsing-query-strings-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for regular expressions. Simply match any string where the first seven characters are "mailto:".

If you insist on using regular expressions, the expression would be "mailto:.*". If you only want to keep what is after the "mailto:", it would be "mailto:(.*)"

Comment: Do you really want to use regex to pull apart a query string? There are libraries specifically designed to do that which will properly handle all the edge cases.

Comment: For the second case, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261222/how-to-use-regular-expressions-to-extract-information-from-mailto-links/2261448#2261448

Answer (score 1):

For first you can use String.startsWith(String prefix)

And second maybe trim string for "?" then use String.split("&|="); and you hav array with 
[ subject, Indian, body, hello]

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

Regex really isn't necessary for this. A simple String.startsWith would suffice for the first match and you could use the [URL](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class to extract the query.

```
String string = "mailto:abc@gmail.com?subject=Indian&body=hello";
if (string.startsWith("mailto:")) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(string);
        String query = url.getQuery(); // Here is your query string.

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new AssertionError("This should not happen: " + e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. mailto:.+ or mailto:[^\s]+
2. mailto:.+?\?(.+) or mailto:[^\s]+?\?[^\s]+