# HttpServletRequest getParameter AND getReader

Tags: java, servlets

I am developing a `HttpServlet` that handles a POST request from an application that includes parameters on the query string, and a JSON object in the body.  It is not a form post, the entire body is the JSON object.  I understand that I need to use `HttpServletRequest.getReader()` to read the body.  But I also need to use `HttpServletRequest.getParameter()` to get the query parameters.  And I understand that both can not be used.

I think the intended solution is to create a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` and override `getReader()` in such a way as to allow it to be called more than once.  But I can't figure out how to do that.  Or maybe this is not the intended approach.  All the examples of `HttpServletRequestWrapper` that I can find seem to be related to creating filters and modifying the contents of the request.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

BTW, this is hosted on Google App Engine, but I don't think that will affect the solution.

Comment: "And I understand that both can not be used"... this is not true.  You can use both without a problem.

Comment: @skaffman: this is not true. Read the last paragraph of `getParameter()` javadoc http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29 POST parameters are sent as request body. So if they are not parsed yet and you read the body, then you won't be able to use `getParameter()` and vice versa.

Comment: @BalusC: The OP says the parameters are in the query string, not the body (i.e. they're not form-encoded). This is allowed even with a POST.

Comment: @skaffman: Ah right. That does then not explain why the OP posted this question. @Darrell: Did you try it yourself anyway? What happens instead? How about `request.getQueryString()`?

Comment: Note that the other getParameter***(..) methods don't have the same warning as getParameter(String). It might be worth checking out if they are in fact safer.

Comment: When I say both can not be used, I mean both methods getReader() and getParameter() can not be used.  The POST from the app does indeed send some infor in the querystring and the main info in the body.  I will try getParameterMap().

Comment: So I tried getParameterMap() and then iterate over the keys and I noticed that there is one key that has the entire body of the request in it.  That entry in the map has no value.  So its a little weird because the key is what I want.  But this doesn't seem like the right way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can implement multiple-callable `getReader()` in your `HttpServletRequestWrapper` :

1. save the HTTP-request body into a temporary file.
2. when `HttpServletRequestWrapper.getReader()` is called, open the temporary file.
3. delete the temporary file at the end of request processing.

to implement (1) and (3), `ServletFilter` may be useful.

Comment: In order to save the body, I would have to call getReader() on the underlying HttpServletRequest, correct?  Which means that all calls to things like getParameters() will now fail.  Do I have to parse all the parameters and headers and everything myself?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading the query string parameters directly by **parsing the query string**. This way you won't touch the message body and you can use `HttpServletRequest.getReader()`.

Parsing the query string is tricky but there it can be done safely using URLEncodedUtils from Apache Http Client package as discussed here:

- [Parsing query strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667278/parsing-query-strings-in-java/6504381)