# Parsing a requestUrl in Java

Tags: java, url-rewriting

I have a request URL i need to parse that URL and have to modify that

EG :if I have request URL like
          **http://www.xyz.com/?a=b&c=d**

Now  I need to modify the value of c or a to something else before redirecting to this URL 
How can I achieve this.

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: This may help, Ashish http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667278/parsing-query-strings-in-java

Comment: See this question on parsing URLs is java, there are a number of possibilities: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667278/parsing-query-strings-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
 public static Map<String, String> getQueryMap(String query)
    {
        String[] params = query.split("&");
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (String param : params)
        {
            String name = param.split("=")[0];
            String value = param.split("=")[1];
            map.put(name, value);
        }
        return map;
    }

    String query = url.getQuery();  
    Map<String, String> map = getQueryMap(query);  
    Set<String> keys = map.keySet();  
    for (String key : keys)  
    {  
       System.out.println("Name=" + key);  
       System.out.println("Value=" + map.get(key));  
    }
```

Comment: This looks fine in this way I am able to modify the content of that URL .But how can I get again get the URL from this map with modified value

Answer (score 0):

invoke [request.getParameterMap](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29) and iterate over the querystring keys and replace with what ever  needed