# What is the equivalent to parse_str in java

Tags: java, php, url, query-string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing query strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667278/parsing-query-strings-in-java)

PHP has [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), is there an equivalent function that does the same thing in java?

Comment: It "names" given to some functions is quite baffling...

Comment: Your question appears to be answered by this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667278/parsing-query-strings-in-java

Comment: @pst On the other hand, Java's taking 30 lines to do what we PHPers do in one is also baffling. We all pick our poisons!

Comment: I think I didn't read the documentation for `parse_str` closely enough - as @Havard S notes in his answer, there are two modes of operation. The question this was marked as a duplicate of points out how to achieve the second part - parsing the query string. AFAIK, the first mode, creating variables isn't possible in Java since it's not a dynamic language, unlike PHP.

Comment: I understand both these questions have the same answer but I do not believe they are the same question.  I tried to search for this before posting and could not find an answer.  Does this question stay available to be searched even if the question is closed?

Comment: I agree with Lumpys remark. This is not a dupe, even if it ends up having the same practical answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHPs `parse_str` has two modes of operation:

1. If given a single argument, `parse_str` will set parameters as variables in the current scope. For this mode of operation, there is no equivalent in Java.
2. If given two arguments, the second argument must be an array which will be populated with the query string parameters/values. For an equivalent in Java, see [this answer on parsing query strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667278/parsing-query-strings-in-java).

Comment: +1 for clarifying what it is that `parse_str` actually does! AFAIK, you can't do the equivalent of #1 in Java since it's not a dynamic language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ServletRequest` object's `getParameter` method. [http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29)