# how to check if a parameter is present in a URL in simplest form

Tags: java

I would like to parse a string which is basically a URL. I need to check simply that a parameters is passed to it or not.

so http://a.b.c/?param=1 would return true http://a.b.c/?no=1 would return false and http://a.b.c/?a=1&b=2.....&param=2 would return true since param is set

I am guessing that it would involve some sort of regular expression.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing query strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667278/parsing-query-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 8):

Java has a builtin library for handling urls: [Spec for URL here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html).

You can create a URL object from your string and extract the query part:

```
URL url = new URL(myString);
String query = url.getQuery();
```

Then make a map of the keys and values:

```
Map params<string, string> = new HashMap<string, string>();
String[] strParams = query.split("&");
for (String param : strParams)  
{  
    String name = param.split("=")[0];  
    String value = param.split("=")[1];  
    params.put(name, value);  
}
```

Then check the param you want with `params.containsKey(key);`

There is probably a library out there that does all this for you though, so have a look around first.

Comment: it throws an exception, the URL can be malformed and we should not care as it could be based on an expression which would be expanded later.

Comment: @geoaxis: Then you would have to do some processing to extract the query string... It depends how 'misformed' your URLs can be (e.g. can they contain unescaped `?`, `&`, `=`, etc.) I would suggest `myString.split("?")[1];` as a first cut.

Comment: @dacwe: A well-formed url can't contain &amp; it would contain `%26amp%3B`

Answer (score 1):

```
String url = "http://a.b.c/?a=1&b=2.....&param=2";
String key = "param";
if(url.contains("?" + key + "=") || url.contains("&" + key + "="))
    return true;
else
    return false;
```