# JAX-RS/Jersey client: unmarshall URI encoded name/value pairs

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs

I wondered if anyone knows how best to unmarshall a response from a JAX-RS/Jersey client that is returning a response from paypal. The response is URI encoded in name/value pairs. I ask because I've already written some code that unmarshalls a google geocode response, given a class hierarchy it automagically transforms the JSON response into objects, but alas I've not been able to do similar with this simpler problem.

```
TIMESTAMP=2011%2d06%2d03T13%3a22%3a17Z&CORRELATIONID=f708c43c1d078&ACK=Success&VERSION=56%
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to do something like this: [Parsing query strings on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667278/parsing-query-strings-in-java/1667624#1667624).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - I had wondered if this was built in to jersey but this is fine.