# How can I get this URL parameter with regex

Tags: java, regex

```
String url = "mysite.com/index.php?name=john&id=432"
```

How can I extract the id parameter (432)?

it can be in any position in the url and the length of the id varies too

Comment: Using a regex is probably the wrong way to go about this - is there a really good reason for using one?

Comment: @PhilipKendall no particular reason, i want want to retrieve the value of `id`

Comment: I understand this approach in script languages or in .htaccess but in java we can use the URL class to parte urls and it is easy to test and maintain. Keep it in mind: you can use regex but probably there is a better way to solve this problem (maybe using regex, maybe not).

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj how? can you post an example

Comment: see this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667278/parsing-query-strings-in-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Apache [URLEncodedUtils](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html) from [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) package:

```
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.List;

public class UrlParsing {
    public static void main(String[] a){
        String url="http://mysite.com/index.php?name=john&id=42";
        List<NameValuePair> args= URLEncodedUtils.parse(url, Charset.defaultCharset());
        for (NameValuePair arg:args)
            if (arg.getName().equals("id"))
                System.out.println(arg.getValue());
    }
}
```

This print 42 to the console.

If you have the url stored in a URI object, you may find useful an overload of URLEncodedUtils.parse
that accept directly an URI instance. If you use this overloaded version, you have to give the charset as a string:

```
URI uri = URI.create("http://mysite.com/index.php?name=john&id=42");
List<NameValuePair> args= URLEncodedUtils.parse(uri, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: it complains about Charset.defaultCharset() it needs a string instead. whats the encoding string look like?

Comment: It's working for me. I'm using version 4.2 of httpclient. Beware that my first version was wrong: I edited my code: are you using the code before my edit?

Comment: Looked at URLEncodedUtils javadoc: it wnat a String as a second parameter if you give the url as an URI instance; otherwise, it accept a Charset as in my code

Answer (score 3):

I just give an abstract regex. add anything you don't want in `id` after `[^&`

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("id=([^&]*?)$|id=([^&]*?)&");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);

if (matcher.matches()) {
    int idg1   = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    int idg2   = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
}
```

either `idg1` or `idg2` has value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
String id = url.replaceAll("^.*?(?:\\?|&)id=(\\d+)(?:&|$).*$", "$1");
```

Comment: fails if it's the first param :)

Comment: that returns the id and the rest of the url (the other parameters). **output** 432&pId=10....

Comment: @user521180: So sorry, omitted the `.*$` part earlier, pls check the edited answer now.

Comment: @user521180: Are you sure, what is your input URL? For me it always returns parameter `id`'s value.

Comment: wow - and people have trouble reading regex and figuring out what they do :-)

Answer (score 0):

The regex has already been given, but you can do it with some simple splitting too:

```
public static String getId(String url) {
        String[] params = url.split("\\?");
        if(params.length==2) {
                String[] keyValuePairs = params[1].split("&");
                for(String kvp : keyValuePairs) {
                        String[] kv = kvp.split("=");
                        if(kv[0].equals("id")) {
                                return kv[1];
                        }
                }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("id not found");
}
```