# Reading facebook access token from redirect uri in Java desktop application

Tags: java, facebook, desktop-application, facebook-oauth, facebook-access-token

"When using a desktop app and logging in, Facebook redirects people to the redirect_uri mentioned above and places an access token along with some other metadata (such as token expiry time) in the URI fragment:

https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#
    access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN...
**Your app needs to detect this redirect and then read the access token out of the URI using the mechanisms provided by the OS and development framework you are using.** You can then skip straight to the Inspecting access tokens step."

This is what facebook documentation says about building a manual login flow through a desktop application. 
My question is how to read the access token from the redirected uri in a java desktop application?

Comment: You mean that you run Java on the server or a Java-applet? If you run Java on the server you can't read it. The hash part of the URL is never sent to the server by web browsers

Comment: If your app is spawning a webview, you may be able to access the current URI being displayed in that webview - how are you opening the login dialog?

Comment: I was just redirecting the following url https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=*********redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token to a desktop browser. The browser shows the login dialog and once you authorize the app, it redirects to url with a access token appended as parameter, but this url stays just for seconds and then it changes to this:https://www.facebook.com/connect/blank.html#_=_

Comment: Did you found an answer?

Answer (score -1):

Have a look am my answer here: [JAVA : how to extract youtube URL from facebook.com/l.php?u=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739237/java-how-to-extract-youtube-url-from-facebook-com-l-phpu/23739362#23739362)

It deals with a similar thing, parsing a URL and looking for a parameter's content. You need to capture the URL which FB redirects to after the successful login. This URL contain the given Access Token.

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0#login

Quote:

> When using a desktop app and logging in, Facebook redirects people to
>   the redirect_uri mentioned above and places an access token along with
>   some other metadata (such as token expiry time) in the URI fragment:
>
> ```
> https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN...
> ```
>
> Your app needs to detect this redirect and then read the access token
>   out of the URI using the mechanisms provided by the OS and development
>   framework you are using.