# How to get partial content in url?

Tags: java, string

url 1 : http://cr2.shopping.naver.com/adcr.nhn?**x=dhjnSwL99ITWnTtJ%2BNcbif%2F%2F%2Fw%3D%3Ds5rXuTvXvEeaqd1LMapU%2FU%2FGYs5Bq2xhAtWlmO9X%2ByC0HNdgYZa86Dt%2Fs%2Fz7OEUUL1hAHF8%2BM4HFSjImNC801nZTDskEtEQbmTqBaIjRJ2Zrgb%2BRdlzPDKW4FFk5yTMTbuTDME%2BhnaIrjajOgxCIrF6Ab7qWwAUAaFXmwYSYm2%2BobW8Q0n1K624WPXQnYRAFxDPAb7dS%2BezuSpS7lne63UwXLaZMsvFkF2BbMDWNeydNCL47yrheZprULMzcvv9y45R3tTbxpYoaYHpLGc%2Bgonz70eUtzBzAvuV%2FSEH06pBp86oeMlgiki9dbDwP9PZmKXmLuhaukQT%2B9%2FMhnlSnrMWGO6LT9sQoYgy%2F7nDF6k8t5KfQvg9rDMmSRUEAalmGCqaBTMNq3zchwlX98MJHPdV6F1eprzVOqyZHx2uCj%2FKjclwziyFVZHP1hD3WCYVjtuY9klE%2BUwceaYdBNdemgQlecrAFITNNiFB8Tm%2FsTSWLuh14vREq%2FGGjSmMm%2B0uw%2B%2BpIkCoKahUdLQHbfDcWRs9adZpUKxMQ%2BelQL1PiMqWExew7ToVYx78MKeYrX0Rxx9skhAYhPiPVASQ40oPriMg%3D%3D**&nv_mid=8092039238&cat_id=50002054

url 2 : http://cr2.shopping.naver.com/adcr.nhn?**x=T1M9wt6JEhq9K7FSJCG%2B4P%2F%2F%2Fw%3D%3Ds42a0gCIQ3fSoQ%2FEVEIVy%2BPGYs5Bq2xhAtWlmO9X%2ByC0IwY84pBogsHz4%2FkZhaYX09wXTpW0ysnyNtuaQs0AnyzXcJa7O5c%2FAbqG%2B46W8cYx5BLLrGiz9Lcdu3uNlSFkaLb8mb5Z3SwCWQIP4ZlXmTy8lVyOVkZbUxHBxtO4FYsK4xPqTAqq7c73Ub%2BAx%2BWuVhebCC3WbDgb6s13t6dhbz6%2Fm3qLgfYP8mpGJNNAmOsEsy0AMLM4z0sMQ3TaEwL5Pa3kNmrsGZGMwIvYg424wN8fzI54Dvwc1MhnN8cYkoYUdbNcIIEWSfPOPj6XPleUZoV78mxVOVsjND%2BCWEhgf5ZhxgkZwwg%2F7PYaL0vrdYCbD9nqbxtnpJ64t3tx6gK%2FGHsFgp6kcG0ZzT8IjCzTPTrXk%2FppF3RDrYdLCGP%2BBjRIfHyaFlZ621AZVGsQCqBxCyLZeFzVun%2BDlZ3K8pIZ4Q49WO4Pow4N4AOr0R2ic5VwopTaiAicvPcJTFXkUQW8SKEArO7HQDTRJyR893w7KyaVL1evn5V%2FVx08i9phKSsfyN20pO6Rhh7d6%2BViGP2vJjgvLF6hYMCZ12QNYa%2Biz4pPLPgEpopImoxepm0ZGzyvGozpTQRWy9WvvHVoeOWG5X1Rl4FzrhSwsFfvy2dKqRA%3D%3D**&nv_mid=8092039238&cat_id=50002054

Hello Friends. 
I'm learning Java. I want to get a partial content with URLs. Please see above urls, I wanna get "x" attribute in url (bold) How to get a "x=......" ?

I used this code :

```
 String link = text.substring(39, 734);
```

but If url's length is diffrent, the code is incorrect. 
how to get exact value on above url? 
I want to get from **x=** to **before &**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728093/how-can-i-get-this-url-parameter-with-regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String url = url1;
int start = url.indexOf("x=");
int end = url.indexOf("&nv_mid=");
String value = url.substring(start, end);
```

Comment: Thank you ! Simple and Easy way

Answer (score 1):

Use the `URI` class:

```
final URI uri = new URI(yourUrlHere);
final String query = uri.getQuery();
```

You can then extract the text you want from `query`.

Additionally you can perform a slew of other checks since the URI class has plenty of methods to grab the different components etc. See [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) for more info.

Comment: Hi. I don't want to get last attribute, "nv_mid=8092039238&cat_id=50002054..." blabla.

Comment: @JuntaeKim this is a very nice answer, u can get absolutely everything. if you don't want something just don't use it. the accepted answer is good but it will gives u error if "x="  or "&nv_mid=" don't atcually exists