# How to get or split the QueryString() parameters in java

Tags: java

How split and print all the parameters inside the QueryString() and pass to enumeration.

Example: `www.xyz.com/page1/a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4`.

QueryString is here: `a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4merat`

I want like this `a=1, b=2, c=3`. We can use `req.getParameters` also.But problem is the QueryString parameters are encoded. So i need to split these parameters only.

If u know pls let me know.
Thanks in Advance.

Shrikant

Comment: You say that the parameters are "encoded", but your example contradicts this.  Please explain what you really mean.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667278/parsing-query-strings-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You could use [URLEncodedUtils.parse(String, Charset)](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html) from [HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/)

> Returns a list of NameValuePairs as parsed from the given string using
>   the given character encoding.