# What's the easiest way to break this String down to key/value strings in Java for Android?

Tags: java, android, for-loop, iterator, key-value

Here is my `String`:

```
&username=john&password=12345&email=john@go.com
```

What is the best and most efficient way to break this down into key/value strings so that they can be added as params. Here's a mock example of what I need:

```
for (set in array)
{
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(set.key, set.value));
}
```

Comment: Where did those strings come from? Are they *actually* part of a query string? If so, you should use something which understands query strings (performing all appropriate unescaping etc).

Comment: It looks suspiciously like a Query String.

Comment: Yes, it's a query string from a 3rd party source. Is there some special way to break those down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
String all = "&username=john&password=12345&email=john@go.com";
//Split across all instances of the 'and' symbol
String[] keyValueConcat = all.split("&");
Map<String, String> kvPairs = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (String concat : keyValueConcat) {
    if (concat.contains("=") {
        //For any string in the split that contains an equals sign
        //Split over the equals sign and add to the map
        String[] keyValueSplit = concat.split("=", 2);
        kvPairs.put(keyValueSplit[0], keyValueSplit[1];
    }
}
```

And the map kvPairs should contain what you need.

Answer (score 2):

See this question: [Parsing query strings on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667278/parsing-query-strings-in-java)

> On Android, the Apache libraries provide a Query parser:

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [StringTokenizer](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-stringtokenizer-example/) (or) [String.split](http://javaeschool.com/java-examples/java-string-split-example/) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
String exp="&username=john&password=12345&email=john@go.com"
String[] pairs=exp.split("&");
String[] temp;
Map<String, String> myMap= new HashMap<String, String>();

for(i=0;i<pairs.length;i++){
temp=pairs[i].split("=");
myMap.put(temp[0],temp[1]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is available in java for android but in Java 8 a string can be broken into key value pair using below:

```
String string = "&username=john&password=12345&email=john@go.com";
Map<String, String> map= Stream.of(string.split("&")).map(p->p.split("=")).filter(p->p!=null && p.length==2).collect(Collectors.toMap(p->p[0], p->p[1]));
```