# Extract a randomly generated ID from URL

Tags: java, url, selenium, extract

I need to extract a randomly generated part of an URL for a Selenium Test in Java.

When the browser opens a page, e.g.:

```
/edit_person.html?id=eb58cea3a3772ff656987792eb0a8c0f
```

then I'm able to show the url with:

```
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
```

but now I need to get only the randomly generated ID after the equals sign.

How do I extract the value of parameter id once I have the entire URL as a string in variable url?

Comment: Use the URI class to get the query part, then parse the query part yourself (cut up along `&`, then cut up along `=`)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667278/parsing-query-strings-in-java

Comment: what have you tried? there are plenty of ways to do this, the `URL` class has methods that make this easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how managed to solve the problem:

```
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        URL aURL = new URL(url);
        url = aURL.getQuery();
        String[] id = url.split("=");
        System.out.println(id[1]);
```

Thanks to Jarrod Roberson!

Answer (score 1):

[`URL.getQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getQuery%28%29) will give the query portion as a String it is a simple regular expression match to isolate the part you want.

`id=(.*)` will get you what you want as long as it is the only thing in the query string.