# How to parse or split URL Address in Java?

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

If I have url address.

https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?limit=25&since=1374196005

Can I get(or split) parameters (avoiding hard coding)?

Like this

**https**  ///  **graph.facebook.com**  ///  **me/home**   ///  **{limit=25, sincse=1374196005}**

Comment: do you want to parse parameters (limit,since) and their value in a map?

Comment: You can use `.split()` to split them based on various delimiters like `/` or `?` . Is that what you want?

Comment: @kevinhoo Map is good for me. or getParmKeys(), and getParmVal(parmKey)?

Comment: you may be you are looking for this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667278/parsing-query-strings-in-java

Comment: @kevinhoo Yes, Before asking, I could not find good answer.

Comment: @ChangUZ before your asking, i use some code i write myself to handle this job.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use Android's `Uri` class.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?limit=25&since=1374196005");
String protocol = uri.getScheme();
String server = uri.getAuthority();
String path = uri.getPath();
Set<String> args = uri.getQueryParameterNames();
String limit = uri.getQueryParameter("limit");
```

Comment: this is what I want. To use getQueryParameterNames in low api level(<11), we can get method in android open source.

Comment: (4.2.2 adroid.net.Uri.getQueryParameterNames() method) http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/net/Uri.java#Uri.getQueryParameterNames%28%29

Comment: This is the right answer. Everyone who said anything about `split()`, myself included, read the question too fast.

Comment: @ChangUZ fyi, the grepcode link does not appear to be working/live.

Answer (score 3):

For pure Java , I think this code should work:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class UrlTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String s = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?limit=25&since=1374196005";
            URL url = new URL(s);
            String query = url.getQuery();
            Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for (String q : query.split("&")) {
                String[] qa = q.split("=");
                String name = URLDecoder.decode(qa[0]);
                String value = "";
                if (qa.length == 2) {
                    value = URLDecoder.decode(qa[1]);
                }

                data.put(name, value);
            }
            System.out.println(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin

https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?limit=25&since=1374196005

```
import java.net.URI
import android.net.Uri
```

```
val uri = URI(viewEvent.qr)
val guid = Uri.parse(uri.fragment).getQueryParameter("c")
```

Answer (score 0):

Built-in `java.net.URL`  should serve.

```
URL url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?limit=25&since=1374196005");

String[] parts = {
   url.getProtocol(), 
   url.getUserInfo(), 
   url.getHost(), 
   url.getPort(), 
   url.getPath(),
   url.getQuery(), 
   url.getRef() 
};
```