# Parsing data from a REST URL

Tags: android, rest, parsing, url

I have a url which looks like this `https://test.sample.com/product/<product_Id>/subproduct/<sub_product_id>`

I'm trying to get the `<product_id>` and `<sub_product_id>` from this in the best clean way possible.

What I've tried is to do a String split, loop through each item and get the items after "product" and "subproduct".

Is this the only way to do this ? Or rather the best possible way ?

Comment: might it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736681/how-to-parse-or-split-url-address-in-java

Comment: @MeetTitan Where does the OP mention JSON anywhere?  I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Thanks @sudha but I had already checked that question and it doesn't solve my purpose (because of multiple variables in the path). It's a good approach to isolate the path from the base URl and other query params

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Splitting the url string is one option, but we can try using `String#replaceAll` for a regex based one liner approach:

```
String url = "https://test.sample.com/product/<product_Id>/subproduct/<sub_product_id>";
System.out.println(url.replaceAll(".*/product/(.*?)/.*$", "$1"));
System.out.println(url.replaceAll(".*/subproduct/(.*?)$", "$1"));

<product_Id>
<sub_product_id>
```

### Demo

Comment: Went ahead with this answer because this insulates the app's code from any changes in the URl structure as long as the IDs are preceded by the key.

Comment: @RmK I don't know what exactly you have in mind by "delimiters," but if you're referring to `/` then no, it doesn't require any special handling.  Forward slash is not a metacharacter.

Comment: Thanks again ! Sorry I removed the comment right after posting it when it hit me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Uri class in android.net.Uri

```
  Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://test.sample.com/product/4/subproduct/8");
    List list =  uri.getPathSegments();
    Log.d("productid",list.get(1).toString());
    Log.d("subproductid",list.get(3).toString());
```

Comment: The only drawback of this approach is that it assumes fixed positions for the two components.

Comment: Thanks Majid. Although I agree with @TimBiegeleisen here because this is going to be used in an app and I wouldn't want do do a new release just because the URL structure got changed.

Answer (score 0):

This works if you know the url will always be formatted the same.
    String url = "https://test.sample.com/product/asdf/subproduct/qwerty";
    String[] urlArray = url.split("/");
    // check may be here if the array is at least more than 7 or whatever length you require.
    String product = urlArray[4];
    String subproduct = urlArray[6];