# extracting sub string using pattern matching in scala

Tags: scala

I want to extract domain name from uri.

For example, input to the regular expression may be of one of the below types

1. test.net
2. https://www.test.net
3. https://test.net
4. http://www.test.net
5. http://test.net

in all the cases the input should return test.net

Below is the code in implemented for my purpose

```
    val re = "([http[s]?://[w{3}\\.]?]+)(.*)".r
```

But I didn't get expected result

below is my output

> val re(prefix, domain) = "https://www.test.net"
>
> prefix: String = https://www.t
>
> domain: String = est.net

what is problem with my regular expression and how can I fix it?

Comment: The dot after 'www' should be escaped. Also, you have square brackets around the whole thing before the plus sign

Comment: okay I've updated it still the same error

Comment: And you're still using square brackets where you should use parentheses. The square brackets only match 1 of those chars, while parens match the entire group. I don't understand your regex but this should at least get you a bit further: "(http(s)?://(w{3}\\.)+?)([^.]*)"

Comment: still same error for your regular expression above ```val re(prefix, domain) = "https://www.test.net"
prefix: String = https://www.t
domain: String = est.net```

Comment: So your domain name is just everything after "www." right? yes

Comment: You don't need regex for this. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736681/how-to-parse-or-split-url-address-in-java) and [this code sample](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/URL_parser#Scala) to see how it can be done using java's URL / URI parser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse a URI String into Name-Value Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection)

Comment: @jrook - No. I'm not looking at that solution. I got solution in answers that I'm expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is problem with my regular expression and how can I fix it?

You are using a [character class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#classes)

```scala
[http.?://(www.)?]
```

This means:

- either an `h`
- or a `t`
- or a `t`
- or a `.`
- or a `?`
- or a `:`
- or a `/`
- or a `/`
- or a `(`
- or a `w`
- or a `w`
- or a `w`
- or a `.`
- or a `)`
- or a `?`

It *does not* include an `s`, so it will not match `https://`.

It is not clear to me why you are using a character class here, nor why you are using duplicate characters in the class.

Ideally, you shouldn't try to parse URIs yourself; someone else has already done the hard work. You could, for example, use the [`java.net.URI`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html) class:

```scala
import java.net.URI

val u1 = new URI("test.net")
u1.getHost
// res: String = null

val u2 = new URI("https://www.test.net")
u2.getHost
// res: String = www.test.net

val u3 = new URI("https://test.net")
u3.getHost
// res: String = test.net

val u4 = new URI("http://www.test.net")
u4.getHost
// res: String = www.test.net

val u5 = new URI("http://test.net")
u5.getHost
// res: String = test.net
```

Unfortunately, as you can see, what you want to achieve does not actually comply with the official URI syntax.

If you can fix that, then you can use `java.net.URI`. Otherwise, you will need to go back to your old solution and parse the URI yourself:

```scala
val re = "(?>https?://)?(?>www.)?([^/?#]*)".r

val re(domain1) = "test.net"
//=> domain1: String = test.net

val re(domain2) = "https://www.test.net"
//=> domain2: String = test.net

val re(domain3) = "https://test.net"
//=> domain3: String = test.net

val re(domain4) = "http://www.test.net"
//=> domain4: String = test.net

val re(domain5) = "http://test.net"
//=> domain5: String = test.net
```

Comment: Except the first case (which is just two strings with a `.` between them) all others can be acquired using `URI` + a check to remove the beginning `www.`. this regex will match "hello. Good morning" while URI will not allow that.

Comment: The problem is that the OP expects in all cases the domain part of the host part of the URI to be `test.net`. However, that is actually only true for cases #3 and #5, where the host is `www` and the domain is indeed `test.net`. In case #2 and #4, the FQDN of the host part is just `net`, and in case #1, the URI doesn't even have a host part at all, it only has a path. So, trying to parse this with an URI parser doesn't work, because the OP's parsing rules are *different* from RFC 2396.

Comment: Since the OP's parsing rules do not follow any official specification, and the OP haven't given their parsing rules, who is to say that "hello. Good morning" *isn't* a valid URI according to their rules?