# Java : how to get text between "http://" and first following "/" occurence ? And after first "/" occurence?

Tags: java, android, regex

I am still a novice with regular expressions, "regex", etc... in Java.

If I have an url like this : "http://somedomain.someextention/somefolder/.../someotherfolder/somepage"

What is the simplest way to get :

- "somedomain.someextention" ?
- "somefolder/.../someotherfolder/somepage" ?
- "somepage" ?

Thanks !

Comment: take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667278/parsing-query-strings-in-java

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to (and probably shouldn't) use regex here. Instead use classes defined to handle things like this. You can use for example `URL`, `URI`, `File` classes like

```
String address = "http://somedomain.someextention/somefolder/.../someotherfolder/somepage";

URL url = new URL(address);
File file = new File(url.getPath());

System.out.println(url.getHost());
System.out.println(url.getPath());
System.out.println(file.getName());
```

Outpit:

```
somedomain.someextention
/somefolder/.../someotherfolder/somepage
somepage
```

Now you can need to get rid of `/` at start of path to your resource. You can use `substring(1)` here if resource starts with `/`.

---

But if you really must use regex you can try with

```
^https?://([^/]+)/(.*/([^/]+))$
```

Now

- group 1 will contain host name,
- group 2 will contain path to resource
- group 3 will contain name of resource

Answer (score 3):

The best way to get those components is to use the `URI` class; e.g.

```
    URI uri = new URI(str);
    String domain = uri.getHost();
    String path = uri.getPath();
    int pos = path.lastIndex("/");
    ...
    // or use File to parse the path string.
```

You *could* do it using regexes on the raw url string, but there is a risk that you won't correctly cope with all of the variability that is possible in a URL.  (Hint: the regex supplied by @Pchenko doesn't :-))  And you would definitely need to use a decoder to deal with possible percent encoding.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a regexp or URI use but simple substring code as an excersise material. Missing few corner case format validation.

```
int lastDelim = str.lastIndexOf('/);
if (lastDelim<0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid url");
int startIdx = str.indexOf("//");
startIdx = startIdx<0 ? 0 : startIdx+2;
int pathDelim = str.indexOf('/', startIdx);
String domain = str.substring(startIdx, pathDelim);
String path = str.substring(pathDelim+1, lastDelim);
String page = str.substring(lastDelim+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use regex to decode the URL instead of using the URI class, as described in the previous answers, the below link gives a nice tutorial of regex, and it explains decoding a sample URL as well. You could learn it there and try it out.

http://www.beedub.com/book/2nd/regexp.doc.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not regex, or scalable at that, it works though:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        SomeClass sclass = new SomeClass();
        String[] string = 
            sclass.parseURL("http://somedomain.someextention/somefolder/.../someotherfolder/somepage");

        System.out.println(string[0]);
        System.out.println(string[1]);
        System.out.println(string[2]);
    }

    private String[] parseURL(String url)
    {
        String part1 = url.substring("http://".length(), url.indexOf("/", "http://".length()));

        String part2 = url.substring("http://".length() + part1.length() + 1, url.lastIndexOf("/"));

        String part3 = url = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

        return new String[] { part1, part2, part3 };
    }
}
```

Output:

```
somedomain.someextention
somefolder/.../someotherfolder
somepage
```