# Get Query String Values JAVA

Tags: java, android

I wanted to know if someone can help me with getting the values from a query string.

This is the example: partygo://qr/?partyId=XXX&uid=XXX&name=XXX

I want to get the values from partyId, uid and name. I really dont know if there is any encoder or sth like that.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe this [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667278/parsing-query-strings-on-android) question can help you

Comment: Maybe use a REGEX  and retrieve your value with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

By *decoding the parameters* like below,

```
public void getParametersFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String partyId = request.getParameter("partyId");
    String uid= request.getParameter("uid");
    String name= request.getParameter("name");
}
```

**Solution 2:**

You can achieve this using below method.

```
public static Map<String, String> getQueryMap(String query)  
{  
    String[] params = query.split("&");  
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();  
    for (String param : params)  
    {  
        String [] p=param.split("=");
        String name = p[0];  
        if(p.length>1)  {
            String value = p[1];  
            map.put(name, value);
        }  
    }  
    return map;  
}
```

So then you can use:

```
Map params=getQueryMap(querystring);
String partyId=(String) params.get("partyId");
String uid=(String) params.get("uid");
String name=(String) params.get("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple **GET** request so you can directly get the value of query string using the request object in **doGet** method

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

```
   String partyid = request.getParameter("partyId");
   //similar do others
```

}